# How to load one JavaScript file from another, and then run some code, as a single atomic operation

Tags: jquery, javascript

The short version: "How do you synthesize a `#include` statement in JavaScript?"

The long version:

I have a JavaScript code file that I want to be able to add to general web pages, without imposing any specific conditions on those pages other than simply that they must contain a <script> tag to load my file.

My file contains code that relies on jQuery, so therefore I need to load jQuery from my file. I am doing this by inserting a <script> tag into the DOM. The problem is that I need to have some code run *immediately* that jQuery is loaded, so that I can ensure that, if the page has an older version of jQuery already loaded, it does not get overwritten by my newly-loaded one (i.e. I am taking a reference to `$` and then calling `jQuery.noConflict(true);`).

To try and achieve this, I am adding an onload/onreadystatechange handler to the dynamically-inserted <script> element. This basically works, *but* the problem is that if the underlying page has anything waiting on the page being ready (i.e. `$.ready(...)`), this code gets run before the handler on the <script> element itself, and therefore things break as that code runs with my newly-loaded jQuery version and not the original version the page loaded and the code is expecting.

```
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js";
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState && this.readyState != "loaded" &&
      this.readyState != "complete")
      return;
    var $ = jQuery;
    jQuery.noConflict(true);
    do_my_stuff($);
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Note that I do not have control over the web pages that my code is being called from, so "make the page load the right version of jQuery" is not a solution. Also, simply in-lining jQuery into my code file is not a great solution as jQuery is rather large (and re-building it with only the necessary features still results in a rather large file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating how `jQuery.getScript()` works, it looks like the best solution is to use `XMLHTTPRequest` to load the desired script into a string, and then simply `eval()` it.

Answer (score 0):

You're including a script that overrides some global (ie. `jQuery`/`$`). This is typically considered very sloppy and you're experiencing why.

A simple solution would be to modify your jQuery to use another namespace, like `$my_version_of_jquery`. ie. avoid the name collision.

A more involved solution would do something with proper dependency injection but that's probably too complex for your use-case.

---

Messy:

```
var my_framework = {};
my_function () {
    my_framework.some_function();
}
```

Dependency injected:

```
manager.add_dependency("my_framework", function () {
    return {};
});
manager.run_with_dependencies(
  [ "my_framework", "some_other_dependency" ], // list of dependencies
  function my_function(my_framework, some_other_dependency) { // instances of dependencies
      my_framework.some_function();
  }
});
```

This would allow you to load two versions of the same framework, if that is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes I know it's overriding a global, that's how jQuery works. I didn't get to choose that. Making my own version of jQuery is not a great solution, it loses any benefits of the browser cacheing the standard version. What do you mean by "proper dependency injection"?

Comment: Proper dependency injection would be a solution where nothing leaks to the global scope. All code runs in it's own scope and gets it's dependencies passed in as arguments (rather than grabbing them from the global scope).

Comment: I updated my solution with the general concept of dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks. Am I right in understanding that you are basically saying "don't use jQuery use something else"? ;-) "manager" doesn't seem to be a standard JavaScript thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your query correctly, you have the following conditions to meet:

- Ensure jQuery is loaded prior to executing your own JavaScript code
- As you only want one script dependency, jQuery must be loaded asynchronously
- If a version of jQuery has already been loaded, don't overwrite the global reference

The easiest solution would be to run an initial test to see whether the global jQuery object exists in the global scope:

```
if ( !window.jQuery ) {
    // jQuery isn't there, so load your jQuery version asynchronously
} else {
    // jQuery is already there, so use the existing version
}
```

For your existing solution to work you'll need to use a different global reference. So, instead of `var $ = jQuery`, you'd use `var $myJq = jQuery.noConflict()`. Note: passing  `true` will remove any existing jQuery reference from the global scope.

Loading two separate versions isn't terribly efficient, so if you can I would suggest using the conditional above to decide what to do. However, if the version is important to your own code then the second solution should work ok.

Comment: The problem case is indeed if jQuery is already loaded and it is too old. I need to load the new version, but not have it interfere with the already-loaded version. The difficulty with your suggestion above is making sure that noConflict() gets called immediately after the new version is loaded. I think the eval() solution is probably the best way around this.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you'd need to use eval to solve this issue. I've created a Fiddle just for clarity - two different versions running together: http://jsfiddle.net/j7gVZ/1/

Apologies if I've misunderstood!

Comment: That's what we already had, which didn't work under some circumstances. Sometimes the $(document).ready() happens after the new jQuery is loaded but before noConflict() is called, so things break.